# HTML loading res/drawable images

Tags: android

I have this html page (assets/page.html), and I want to load the image "res/drawable-xhdpi/image.png". There is a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution!

I made a copy of the image.png from the res folder to the assets folder (now assets/image.png).
Then I just srced the image `src="image.png"`